# Proving that $\dfrac{\tan(x+y)-\tan x}{1+\tan(x+y)\tan x}=\tan y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Edit: got it, silly mistakes :)

I need to prove that $\dfrac{\tan(x+y)-\tan x}{1+\tan(x+y)\tan x}=\tan y$

$$=\frac{\tan x+\tan y-\tan x+\tan^2x\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y+\tan^2x+\tan x\tan y}$$

$$=\frac{\tan y+\tan^2x\tan y}{1+\tan^2x}$$

$$=\frac{(\tan y)(1+\tan^2x)}{(1+\tan^2x)}$$

$$\boxed{=\tan y}$$
Any hints/help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there!
$$\dfrac{\color{blue}{\tan x}+\tan y-\color{blue}{\tan x}+\tan^2x\tan y}{1-\color{green}{\tan x \tan y}+\tan^2x+\color{green}{\tan x\tan y}}$$
Then just factor our the $\tan y$ from the numerator.

Comment: Oh wow, loool didn't notice that yeesh. Silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Recall that 
$$\tan(u-v)=\frac{\tan u-\tan v}{1+\tan u\tan v}.\tag{1}$$ Let $u=x+y$ and $v=x$.

**Remark:** If Identity (1) requires proof, use
$$\tan(u-v)=\frac{\sin(u-v)}{\cos(u-v)}=\frac{\sin u\cos v-\cos u\sin v}{\cos u\cos v+\sin u\sin v},$$
and divide top and bottom by $\cos u\cos v$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$$

$$a=\tan x\;\;and\;\;b=\tan y$$

$$\dfrac{\tan(x+y)-\tan x}{1+\tan(x+y)\tan x}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{1-ab}-a}{1+\frac{a+b}{1-ab}a}$$

$$=\frac{a+b-a(1-ab)}{1-ab+a(a+b)}$$

$$=\frac{b(a^2+1)}{a^2+1}$$

$$=b=\tan y$$